# Why do I need to rebuild after updating a lib dll

Tags: .net, dll

I use a lib DLL file for a lot of my common code which I push around from project to project.  Whenever I need a new feature on one of my projects, I grab and compile the most recent version of the lib DLL source, then copy and paste from `MyCommonLib\bin\Release\MyCommonLib.dll` to `MyProject\lib`.

If I run the program immediately, I find it's still using the *old* version of the DLL!  Shouldn't that file have been deleted by the copy w/ overwrite?  I need to `Build All` on my solution to make it recognize the new DLL.

Comment: Is "MyProject\lib" the folder where you have thirdparty libraries? And when you say "run the program", are you running it from the \lib folder? Or from its corresponding \bin\Release folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to make sure that the DLL is copied into the bin folder of the project that is used as the startup project.

By building the startup project, this should copy the referenced DLLs into the bin folder of the main project within the solution.

If this is not the case you might need to write a post-build step for the startup project that will copy all the DLLs that it needs into its bin folder.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

So the basic problem is the copy process, especially for statically referenced assemblies, doesn't occur if the project hasn't changed (i.e. doesn't need rebuilt) and so that's why if you run immediately you see the old version still.

You could circumvent this by adding a post build event to copy the file so regardless of whether or not the project needed rebuilt it would fire.

Answer (score 0):

In the references list in Visual Studio, click Properties and check out "Copy Local" property. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1zz5y8c%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) is the explanation. If you can put that lib in GAC and update the GAC whenever you made any changes, obviously you don't need to rebuild(copy) because your application will resolve it to GAC anyway. If it's not in GAC, technically you can still set "Copy Local" to false and subscribe AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event to manually resolve the lib dll. But then you are facing a much more complicated deployment scenario. Normally people just use the default "Copy Local" value - false to copy the lib dlls to the output folder.